# dart Exception in Directory List

Tags: dart

I'm new to this dart stuff and having problems with creating a list directory.tell me how to handle the exception so that the loop continues

```
void main() async{
  Directory baseDir=new Directory('l:\\');
  print(baseDir.path);
  try {
    await for (var entity in baseDir.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false)){
      print(entity);
      }
     }
  
  catch(e) {
    print("Error: $e");       
    } 
  }
```

Error: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = 'l:$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18*' (OS Error: access denied.
, errno = 5)

```
catch(e) {
        print("Error: $e");
        continue;

        
    }
```

does not work because it is not in the loop body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Stream.handleError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/handleError.html) to swallow `FileSystemException`s:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  var baseDir = Directory.current;

  var stream = baseDir
      .list(
        recursive: true,
        followLinks: false,
      )
      .handleError(
        (e) => print('Ignoring error: $e'),
        test: (e) => e is FileSystemException,
      );
  await for (var entity in stream) {
    print(entity);
  }
  print('Completed successfully.');
}
```

I don't have a Windows machine handy with a Dart development environment, but trying to simulate an equivalent situation as yours on my Linux machine:

```
$ mkdir someSubdir
$ chmod ugo-rx someSubdir # Remove permissions to list or enter the directory.
$ dart dirlist.dart
Directory: '/tmp/dirlist/someSubdir'
Ignoring error: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/tmp/dirlist/someSubdir' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
File: '/tmp/dirlist/dirlist.dart'
Completed successfully.
```

Also see: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods